# The norm of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, convolution, lp-spaces

Let $\rho(x)$ be a weight function in a unit sphere, such that
\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle 1. \rho(x)\ge 0,\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rho(x)=1\\
\displaystyle 2. \rho(x)\in \mathrm{C}_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \\
\displaystyle 3. \rho(x)=0 \mbox{ if $|x|\ge1$}
\end{array} 
\end{equation}
We define $\rho_{\varepsilon}(x)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rho(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$,$u_{\varepsilon}(x)=(\rho_{\varepsilon}*u)(x)$.

$\Omega$ is the domain of $u$,when $x\not\in \Omega$, $u(x)=0$.

Is it true that the operator $A_{\epsilon}:L^{p}(\Omega)\to L^{p}(\Omega)$ $$A_{\epsilon}(u)= u_\varepsilon$$
 satisfies:
$$||A_{\epsilon}-I||\ge 1$$
Moreover, $$||A_{\epsilon}-I||=1$$

I know that
$$\int_{B_{\epsilon}(0)}u(x-y)\rho_{\varepsilon}(y)dy=\int_{\Omega}u(z)\rho_{\varepsilon}(x-z)dz$$
But I am confused by the way to $\sup\frac{||Ax||}{||x|}$ , I am not familiar with convolution. Thanks for your help.